# Best way to update files between folders

Tags: .net, filesystems, directory, copy, updates

I have two directories (`dirA` and `dirB`), and i want to copy all files from `dirA` **including sub-folders** to `dirB` where a file in `dirA` replaces a file in `dirB` only if the two files have the same name (and also the same sub-path) and also `fileB.LastWriteTime < fileA.LastWriteTime`, or else if a file in `dirA` is not present in `dirB`.

So, if I have these directories:

```
<directory Name="dirA">

   <file Name="file1" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
   <file Name="file2" LastWriteTime="11:00" />
   <file Name="file7" LastWriteTime="12:00" />

   <directory Name="subDir">
      <file Name="file3" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
      <file Name="file4" LastWriteTime="11:00" />
   </directory>

   <directory Name="subDir2">
      <file Name="file5" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
      <file Name="file6" LastWriteTime="11:00" />
   </directory>

</directory>

<directory Name="dirB">

   <file Name="file1" LastWriteTime="09:00" />
   <file Name="file2" LastWriteTime="13:00" />

   <directory Name="subDir">
      <file Name="file3" LastWriteTime="09:00" />
      <file Name="file4" LastWriteTime="12:00" />
   </directory>

   <directory Name="BsubDir2">
      <file Name="file5" LastWriteTime="09:00" />
   </directory>

</directory>
```

After the update `dirB` will be:

```
<directory Name="dirB">

   <file Name="file1" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
   <file Name="file2" LastWriteTime="13:00" />
   <file Name="file7" LastWriteTime="12:00" />

   <directory Name="subDir">
      <file Name="file3" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
      <file Name="file4" LastWriteTime="12:00" />
   </directory>

   <directory Name="BsubDir2">
      <file Name="file5" LastWriteTime="09:00" />
   </directory>

   <directory Name="subDir2">
      <file Name="file5" LastWriteTime="10:00" />
      <file Name="file6" LastWriteTime="11:00" />
   </directory>

</directory>
```

Thanks.

Comment: [What Have You Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) <-- I swear there should be a short hand for this

Comment: I tried [this](http://ideone.com/UxL8g)

Comment: `ROBOCOPY source dest /XO`, OK I know is not a programming solution, but sometimes why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Steve because my wheel has a different rim, I need a programming solution.

Comment: OK seriously now, looking at your code I can say that you can get a good optimization using File.Exist and Directory.Exist to avoid the loops on dest to find the existence of the dir/file

Comment: @Steve thanks, I had not thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution for you. Tried and tested with some files, 
Worked fine, but I think more test are needed

```
Private Sub UpdateRec(Src As String, Dest As String, IsTest As Boolean)

    ' Update files in dest dir 
    For Each fileSrc As String In Directory.GetFiles(Src)
        Dim srcInfo As New FileInfo(fileSrc)
        Dim destFile As String = Path.Combine(Dest, srcInfo.Name)
        Dim foundFile As Boolean = File.Exists(destFile)
        if foundFile = true then
            Dim destInfo As New FileInfo(destFile)
          ' Copy only if newer 
          If Not IsTest AndAlso destInfo.LastWriteTime < srcInfo.LastWriteTime Then
              File.Copy(srcInfo.FullName, destInfo.FullName, True)
          End If
        else
        'File not found in dest copy always
        If Not IsTest Then File.Copy(srcInfo.FullName, destFile)
        end if
    Next

    ' Update folder in dest
    For Each dirSrc As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Src)
        Dim srcInfo As New DirectoryInfo(dirSrc)
        Dim dstDir As String = Path.Combine(Dest, srcInfo.Name)
        Dim foundDir As Boolean = Directory.Exists(dstDir)
        ' Not found, create 
        if foundDir = false then
         Directory.CreateDirectory(dstDir)
        end if
        ' recurse to copy file and other subdirs
        Call Me.UpdateRec(dirSrc, dstDir, IsTest)
    Next
End Sub
```

Now it's time to go to bed. Buonanotte.

Comment: I was just writing the same things at the moment. This is what I was looking. Grazie.

Answer (score 1):

Simple recursion, relative to the root path in both locations.

Here's the general algorith. Psuedocodish. This won't compile.

```
// To copy left-to-right:
void CopyFrom(DirectoryInfo left, DirectoryInfo right) {
    foreach(FileInfo leftFile in left.Files) {
        if( !rightContainsFile( leftFile.Name ) ) {
            leftFile.CopyTo( Path.Combine( right.FullPath, leftFile.Name );
        }//if
    }//foreach

    foreach(DirectoryInfo leftDir in left.Directories) {
        DirectoryInfo rightChild;
        if( (rightChild = rightContainsDirectory( leftDir.Name ) ) == null ) {
            // right does not contain child of the same name
            // so create it
            rightChild = Directory.Create( Path.Combine( right.FullPath, leftChild.Name );
        }
        // recursive copy:
        CopyFrom( leftChild, rightChild );
    } //foreach

}//void
```

Some assembly required. HTH.

Comment: Looks very similar to my solution, maybe there's a better way